# Difference between XML and HTML

Tags: xml, html

I know it's a very generic question but still i didn't get any proper answer for this question on internet.

```
**Difference between XML and HTML**
```

any help!!!

Comment: xml is used as database or store light wieght information on webspace or to tranfer datas and html is used for building front pages of websites both cannot be campared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML and HTML are different languages. They belong to the family of markup languages, but they are different. They may look same on the first sight, but they are not. Also their purpose is different. XML is defined to represent a data structure, while HTML represents a presentation layer. There is a mixture of HTML and XML, called XHTML and this is basically HTML expressed in XML.

see more here:

[http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1204/XML/htmlVxml.html](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/%7Ecs1204/XML/htmlVxml.html)

http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-html-and-xml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML

Answer (score 2):

No XML did not replace HTML, Both HTML and XML are different. 
HTML is used for viewing data in proper format, like how it should look and what styling and color should be their (using CSS)

where as xml is used to carry data.
in very simple example you are using stackoverflow and you are seeing the view and you have put on the question. 
what happened on backend?
You put on the question, that is stored on the database of this website.
now next time you login you find the same question here.
Actually main  thing is REST Service is bringing back the data in xml format and that data is being displayed with the help of HTML

Answer (score 2):

Some people originally hoped that XML would replace HTML: that instead of generic tags like `<p>` and `<b>`, people would use semantically-meaningful tags like `<price>` and `<quantity>`, and use a stylesheet to describe the formatting. But it didn't work out that way. Instead, HTML moved incrementally in the same direction, by deprecating the "pure formatting" tags like `<font>`, using `<div class='x'>` where XML would use `<x>`, and moving more and more of the formatting into CSS. Of course, many people still generate HTML from XML, because CSS still has its limitations. So one could say that most of the aims of XML were achieved, but with less disruption to existing syntax.